# Definition of $\rightarrow$.

Tags: logic, notation, definition

Is the definition of $p\rightarrow q$ in logic $(\lnot p) \lor q$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes . . . and no.

In classical logic, yes, $p\to q$ is defined (sometimes) as $(\lnot p)\lor q$. However, classical logic is not the only logic in town. Sometimes other symbols are used to indicate the difference,  such as $p\supset q$, but such notation is also used for the material conditional, which is what is typically meant by $p\to q$.

So it depends.

Comment: You've got a typo; I think you accidentally replaced the "or" symbol with an arrow.

Comment: Well spotted, @TannerSwett; I've corrected it now. Thank you!